# Import model error from one app to another app

Tags: python, django, models

I have 2 app inside a django project. I want to import a model from one app to another. But it gives me

> NameError: name 'JobGenre' is not defined

when I try to syncdb

In `customer.models`

```
from job.models import JobGenre
class Worker(Costumer):
   keyword=models.ForeignKey(JobGenre, null=True)
```

and in `job.models`

```
class JobGenre(models.Model):
    genre=models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

if i use

```
keyword=models.ForeignKey('job.models.JobGenre', null=True)
```

it gives

> Error: One or more models did not validate:
>   costumer.worker: 'keyword' has a relation with model job.models.JobGenre, which has          either not been installed or is abstract.

What should I do in this situation?

Comment: is the `JobGenre` table new ?, If so you need to either drop your database and recreate, or use `django-south`, create migrations and apply it on your database tables

Comment: the whole database is new, it is waiting for sync with the project

Comment: do you have an `__init__.py` in `job` ?>

Comment: I suspect you've failed to include the `job` application in your `settings.py` `INSTALLED_APPS` list.

Comment: I have job app in INSTALLED_APP too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
keyword=models.ForeignKey('job.models.JobGenre', null=True)
```

Looks incorrect to me.

Try instead:

```
keyword.models.ForeignKey('job.JobGenre', null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to give the full package path to ForeignKey method. Just giving appname.modelclass will work.

```
keyword=models.ForeignKey('job.JobGenre', null=True)
```

should work. please refer [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey).